# How to "typedef" a matrix in C

Tags: c

when defining new data types in C, one can do

```
    typedef double BYTE;
```

so later it is possible to do

```
BYTE length;
```

etc

I would like to do something like

```
typedef double[30][30][10] mymatrix;
```

so later I do

```
mymatrix AA[10];
```

so I have 10 matrices of type mymatrix, and I can access them through AA[0], AA[1], etc

Anyway doing this with the GNU C compiler I get errors like

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
```

What am I doing wrong or how could I achieve my objective?

Thanks

Comment: one last question. now it works and I can do: mymatrix AA[10], how do I access the elements of each matrix? I tried, for instance, for the first matrix, AA[0][1][2][3], is this right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow ["declaration looks like use"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations) C idea:

```
typedef double mymatrix[30][30][10];
```

Comment: one last question. now it works and I can do: mymatrix AA[10], how do I access the elements of each matrix? I tried, for instance, for the first matrix, AA[0][1][2][3], is this right?

Comment: You only have **3 dimensions** here, use three indexes: `AA[i][j][k]`.

Comment: he's declaring a 10-element array of type `mymatrix`, which is a 30x30x10 array of `double`; thus, he's ultimately working with four dimensions.

Comment: @John, thanks (bad eyes :) - so right `AA[matrix_index][i][j][k]`.

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is define an object named & declared as you want, then stick `typedef` in front:

```
double mymatrix[30][30][10] ; // defines a 3-d array.


typdef double mymatrix[30][30][10] ; // defines a 3-d array type

mymatrix  matrix;
```

Comment: I wish I was taught this way to look at typedefs in training courses as it would have made understanding typedefs and function pointers so much easier. It took me ages to really appreciate that typedefs aren't actually that complicated

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
typedef double mymatrix[30][30][10];
```

Comment: Oh, seems like Nikolai was a little bit quicker at typing ;-)